# Capturar IDENT_CURRENT c#

Tags: c#, sql

estoy necesitando de su ayuda. Estoy empezando en esto de la programacion y me surgio una duda.
Yo tengo una base de datos con un procedimiento que realiza inscripciones. Una vez que se realiza la inscripcion, devuelve el numero de inscripcion creado.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AGREGARINSCRIPCION
@CI int,
@IDECURSO varchar(15),
@EMPLEADO varchar(15)
AS
begin
if not exists(SELECT CEDULA FROM ALUMNO WHERE CEDULA=@CI)
return -1--NO EXISTE EL ALUMNO
if not exists(SELECT IDECURSO  FROM CURSO WHERE IDECURSO=@IDECURSO)
return -2--NO EXISTE EL CURSO
if exists(SELECT IDECURSO FROM INSCRIPCION WHERE IDECURSO=@IDECURSO AND CEDULA=@CI)
return -3--EL ALUMNO YA ESTA INSCRIPTO
INSERT INSCRIPCION(CEDULA,IDECURSO,FECHAINSCRIPCION,EMPLEADO)
VALUES(@CI,@IDECURSO,GETDATE(),@EMPLEADO)
RETURN IDENT_CURRENT('INSCRIPCION')--NÚMERO DE INSCRIPCIÓN CREADO
end
```

Ahora mi duda es, como puedo capturar ese IDENT_CURRENT para mostrarlo en un formulario en c#?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para eso, debes de utilizar parámetros de salida

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.AgregarInscripcion");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter parameter= new SqlParameter();
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
    parameter.ParameterName = "@Ci";
    parameter.Value = Ci;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter();
    parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    parameter2.ParameterName = "@NumInsert";
    parameter2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
    parameter2.Value = 0;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

    SqlParameter parameter3 = new SqlParameter();
    parameter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    parameter3.Size = 15;
    parameter3.ParameterName = "@IDECURSO";
    parameter3.Value = IdeCurso;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter3);

    SqlParameter parameter4 = new SqlParameter();
    parameter4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter4.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    parameter4.Size = 15;
    parameter4.ParameterName = "@Empleado";
    parameter4.Value = Empleado;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter4);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@NumInsert"].Value);

}
```

En el procedure, tienes que retocar varias cosas.

- No utilices return para devolver valores, y utiliza el [parámetros output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp);
- No utilices Ident_Current, cambia por [ScopeIdentity](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15);

A nivel de SQL.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AGREGARINSCRIPCION
    (
       @CI        int
     , @IDECURSO  varchar(15)
     , @EMPLEADO  varchar(15)
     , @NUMINSERT int OUTPUT
    )
    AS
    begin
        if not exists (SELECT CEDULA  FROM ALUMNO  WHERE CEDULA = @CI ) 
            Set @NUMINSERT = -1;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            if not exists (SELECT IDECURSO FROM CURSO  WHERE IDECURSO = @IDECURSO ) 
                Set @NUMINSERT = -2;
            ELSE
                if exists (SELECT IDECURSO FROM INSCRIPCION WHERE IDECURSO = @IDECURSO AND CEDULA = @CI) 
                    Set @NUMINSERT = -3;
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO INSCRIPCION(CEDULA
                                          , IDECURSO
                                          , FECHAINSCRIPCION
                                          , EMPLEADO)
                    VALUES
                           ( @CI, @IDECURSO, GETDATE(), @EMPLEADO );
                    Set @NUMINSERT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                END;
            
        END;
        RETURN;
    END;
    GO
```